# Android BLE - Device keep disconnecting after a succesfull characteristic write

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, disconnect

I'm working on a mobile app that implements Bluetooth LE and communicates with a HC-08 device.

While everything is ok on iOS with CoreBluetooth, i encounter some problems on my Android version.

I start by getting a Bluetooth Device

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
```

After that, i connect to it:

```
bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, false, callback);
```

Which is calling a callback function inside which i wait for STATE_CONNECTED and discover services, then write to characteristic:

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);


        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "onConnectionStateChange with success");

            if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){
                Log.e("BLE_LOG", "sucessfully connected to device: " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + "/" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());

                bluetoothGatt = gatt;
                gatt.discoverServices();

            }
            else if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){
                Log.e("BLE_LOG", "succesfully Disconnected from device: " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + "/" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
                gatt.close();
            }

        }
        else{
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "onConnectionStateChange with status: " + status + " and newState: " + newState);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "sucessfully discovered services for device: " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + "/" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());

            service = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(BLEFunctions.PROPRIETARY_SERVICE));
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(BLEFunctions.PROPRIETARY_CHARACTERISTIC));

            //Souscription notifications
            if(bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)){
                Log.e("BLE_LOG", "subscribed to notifications from characteristic");
            }

            characteristic.setValue(SET_ON);
            characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);

            bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

        }
        else{
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "Error discovering services for device: " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + "/" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress() + " with status: " + status);
        }

    }
```

When services are discovered, i'm writting to characteristic, which actually work because my bluetooth device is acting as expected (it switches on a relay), and onCharacteristicWrite is called:

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "sucessfully written characteristic for device: " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + "/" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
        }
        else{
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "Error writing characteristic for device: " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + "/" + bluetoothDevice.getAddress() + " with status: " + status);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, as soon as the characteristic is written, the device disconnect and i can't continue my process.

At a point in the program, i've got connectionStateChange with status 8 (which seems to be : GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHORIZATION)

I investigated several potential causes, as :

-Maybe the characteristic needs bonding before writing? I know it is handled automatically on iOS for example.

-Maybe the device i use has some incompatibilities with Android (but it works well with software like 'LightBlue', 'BLE Scanner', etc...

Can't figure out what is wrong.

Please help me solve this problem

Adding the log to help:

```
2022-05-05 09:58:25.600 22204-22204/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG:  clicked on device: Hall/B0:B1:13:76:0B:1E

2022-05-05 09:58:26.065 22204-22467/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG: onConnectionStateChange with success

2022-05-05 09:58:26.068 22204-22467/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG: sucessfully connected to device: AAA-000000000001001/B0:B1:13:76:0B:1E

2022-05-05 09:58:26.727 22204-22467/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG: sucessfully discovered services for device: AAA-000000000001001/B0:B1:13:76:0B:1E

2022-05-05 09:58:26.732 22204-22467/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG: subscribed to notifications from characteristic

2022-05-05 09:58:26.754 22204-22467/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG: sucessfully written characteristic for device: AAA-000000000001001/B0:B1:13:76:0B:1E

2022-05-05 09:58:31.854 22204-22467/com.******.******E/BLE_LOG: onConnectionStateChange with status: 8 and newState: 0
```

Using my device with software like nRF Connect or LightBlue works well. (no disconnection)

[image]

I made progress and managed to point out a reason why the problem occures.

Actually, i'm discovering services via

```
gatt.discoverServices();
```

and as soon as i get the callback method, i get the service and characteristic i need and write to it.

```
@Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

        if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
            Log.e("BLE_LOG", "successfully discovered services");
        }

        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

        Log.e("BLE_LOG", "got serivce with uuid: " + service.getUuid().toString());

        bluetoothGatt = gatt;
        characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

        Log.e("BLE_LOG", "got characteristic with uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());

        byte[] data = {
                0x24, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x25
        };

        characteristic.setValue(data);
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
```

When i deport the write part in another function, like a button function, it works well and doesn't disconnect.

```
public void clicked_open(View v){

    byte[] data = {
            0x24, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x25
    };

    characteristic.setValue(data);
    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

}
```

It's as if something wasn't totally finished when i call my write as soon as i get the service discovered callback.

Maybe there is a way to ensure everything is ok before writing...

Comment: "At a point in the program, i've got connectionStateChange with status 8 (which seems to be : GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHORIZATION)" Forgot to mention that it occures after succesfull write. Maybe at the time of disconnection...

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add your actual log output?

Comment: Sure, what part would you like to see? My "BLE_LOG" entries? Something else?

Comment: The BLE_LOG entries should help. I'm specifically looking for the reason for the disconnect. The log might also show a possible problem in your communication flow

Comment: Added my log ;)

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Hi! did you, by any chance, take a look at the log i posted? Thanks

Comment: It did not give me any more hints, unfortunately. Does the characteristic you're trying to access have any restrictions or does it require authorization/encryption?

Comment: Not as far as i know. Poorly documented. I'll check from my program. What kind of restrictions should i look for?

Comment: Please install a generic BLE scanner app like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) and see how the characteristic behaves when reading or writing using your android phone. Also take a look at the properties (e.g. READ, WRITE) of the characteristic. Feel free to add a screenshot to your question

Comment: I thought i had stated it in my original post, but that's the first thing i did to compare. I installed LightBlue and BLEScanner. Both work well with my device and does not disconnect.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I edited my original post by adding a picture of my device in nRF Connect.

Comment: Oh, sorry, must have missed that. Thanks for the additional info. Sadly, I'm out of ideas. Since everything seems to work using third-party apps the fault must be in your app. But I don't see anything, sorry...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me anyway ;)
Out of ideas too

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan: Hi, sorry to bother you but i made interesting progress regarding my problem. Could you take a little look? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you realized in your last edit, you are writing to the characteristic too soon. `onServicesDiscovered` is called multiple times, once for each found characteristic. You are already checking for the finished discovery and just need to move your writing operation there.

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

    BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

    Log.e("BLE_LOG", "got serivce with uuid: " + service.getUuid().toString());

    if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
        Log.e("BLE_LOG", "successfully discovered services");
    

        bluetoothGatt = gatt;
        characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

        Log.e("BLE_LOG", "got characteristic with uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());

        byte[] data = {
            0x24, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x25
        };

        characteristic.setValue(data);
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
}
```

The parameter `status` will only be `GATT_SUCCESS` after the discovery finished, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onServicesDiscovered(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int)) for more information.

Comment: That's exactly what i have in my final project. I only try to write if "GATT_SUCCESS". But itt doesn't work either...
It only works when delaying write with 250ms

Comment: I just realized that I also use a delay of one second. In my case, there was no signal after enabling notifications, so I had to wait to make sure I could write. But this was only an example project...

Comment: So i'm not the only one in this case. Seems like 250ms is enough in my case...
Don't know if it is a normal behavior...
I don't have such problems in my iOS version. Core Bluetooth is really well written and easy to use.

Comment: Bluetooth needs to send one message at a time. Without the appropriate signaling, you just don't know when to send the next message. We use CoreBluetooth as well, and believe me, there are some problems as well ;) There is no timeout if your device goes out of range, for example. But I also believe Apple did a better job developing their Bluetooth stack in general.